# PF_NULLABLE parse framework difficult to understand, sending Message's to PFUser

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, objective-c-nullability

With Xcode 6.3 Parse. framework was giving me errors, so I download the updated Parse framework and things started working.

Now, there is something new which I am trying to understand what this method `logInWithUsername` is.  Previously it used to pretty simple. I see more null while writing the code. And at some point I get confused, mainly with pointer to a pointer (i.e `NSError`).

> ```
> [PFUser logInWithUsername:(NSString * __nonnull) 
>                  password:(NSString * __nonnull) 
>                     error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing * __nullable)];
> ```

When I jump to definition, it's a quite a different story, the syntax seems to be clear here:

> ```
> + (PF_NULLABLE instancetype)logInWithUsername:(NSString *)username
>                                      password:(NSString *)password
>                                         error:(NSError **)error;
> ```

Am I missing something on configuration or setup side for this framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Objective-C end, you could completely ignore these nullability annotations.  These are strictly there for interfacing with Swift and allowing whether Swift should treat the object as an optional or non-optional, rather than treating everything as an implicitly unwrapped optional.

If we translate your Objective-C method:

> ```
> [PFUser logInWithUsername:(NSString * __nonnull) 
>                  password:(NSString * __nonnull) 
>                     error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing * __nullable)];
> ```

The Swift equivalent would be:

```
PFUser.logIn(username: String, password: String, error: inout NSError?)
```

The gist of it is this: The method does not accept `nil` for the username or password arguments, but it expects an optional reference to an optional error object.

That is, it doesn't matter if your pointer is `nil`, or if what it points to is `nil` (both are allowed to be `nil`).  The method will sort it out.

If you call the method and pass `nil` for the error parameter, you are passing a `nil` pointer.  If you pass an uninitialized `NSError` pointer (`NSError *error = nil;`), you are passing a non-`nil` pointer to a `nil` pointer to an `NSError` object.

But again, if you are working with this library from the Objective-C side, you can ignore this completely.  It works just like it always did.  This only makes an impact from the Swift end where the compiler is strict about the nullability of parameters.

For more reading on Objective-C nullability annotations, [see this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29401454/2792531).