# Swift: Why is label.text an optional but textView.text is an unwrapped String?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitextview, option-type

I tried out the following code in playground

```
import UIKit

let label = UILabel()
let textView = UITextView()

let labelText = label.text           // nil
let textViewText = textView.text     // ""
```

If I Option click `lableText`, the type is `String?`.
If I Option click `textViewText`, the type is `String!`.

Why is the Label text an optional while the TextView text isn't?

Comment: In what exact version of Xcode?

Comment: I got the same results testing this in Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7.0 beta.

Comment: Ultimately, the answer is that Apple hasn't finished updating all of their libraries to use [Objective-C nullability annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29401454/2792531).  Eventually, there should be no implicitly unwrapped optionals (`!`) left in the Apple libraries (by the time they're done).

Comment: Apparently this still stands as a legitimate question in 2023. @nhgrif if Apple was working on updating these values they would have done it already.