# Can't conform to obj-c protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I'm creating an iOS app with Swift. I discovered an animation I'd like to implement in my table view, but the code is in Objective-C.

Repository: https://github.com/recruit-mp/RMPZoomTransitionAnimator

I have successfully bridged Obj-C code to Swift but can't seem to conform to a required protocol.

The protocol:

```
@protocol RMPZoomTransitionAnimating <NSObject>

@required

- (UIImageView *)transitionSourceImageView;
- (UIColor *)transitionSourceBackgroundColor;
- (CGRect)transitionDestinationImageViewFrame;

@end
```

My Swift implementation:

First class that implements the protocol:

```
class ChallengeViewController: UIViewController, RMPZoomTransitionAnimating
   func transitionSourceImageView() -> UIImageView {
        return imageView
    }

    func transitionSourceBackgroundColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    func transitionDestinationImageViewFrame() -> CGRect {
        return imageView.frame
    }
```

Second class:

```
class ChallengeTableViewController: UITableViewController, RMPZoomTransitionAnimating
    func transitionSourceImageView() -> UIImageView {
        return imageForTransition!
    }

    func transitionSourceBackgroundColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    func transitionDestinationImageViewFrame() -> CGRect {
        return imageFrame!
    }
```

This check that occurs before animating always fails:

```
Protocol *animating = @protocol(RMPZoomTransitionAnimating);
    BOOL doesNotConfirmProtocol = ![self.sourceTransition conformsToProtocol:animating] || ![self.destinationTransition conformsToProtocol:animating];
```

I've read this topic [How to create class methods that conform to a protocol shared between Swift and Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399871/how-to-create-class-methods-that-conform-to-a-protocol-shared-between-swift-and) but didn't found any help

Any clues would be really appreciated

Comment: There is a `sourceTransition` and a `destinationTransition`. They are two different objects. They must _both_ conform to RMPZoomTransitionAnimating. But you have only shown _one_ object that conforms to RMPZoomTransitionAnimating. Where's the other one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create class methods that conform to a protocol shared between Swift and Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399871/how-to-create-class-methods-that-conform-to-a-protocol-shared-between-swift-and)

Comment: @Jeef I'll have a look at it now

Comment: Okay, so what's your evidence that "This check that occurs before animating always fails"? You _do_ conform to the protocol; if you didn't, the compiler would stop you and the code wouldn't even run. So what's the _actual problem_ at this point?

Comment: Also - its possible you are going to have to use UnsafeMutalbePointers

Answer (score 0):

Swift classes by themselves are not (by default) Objective-C Compatible.

You get compatibility by either inheriting from `NSObject` or adding `@objc` in front of your class.  I suspect this "may" be your issues - but I unfortunately can't test it at the moment.

You may also have to add a few initializers like in your case one from `NSCoder` or something - I don't unfortunately recall off the top of my head - and I don't have access to Xcode right now.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Try:

```
@objc
class ChallengeViewController: UIViewController, RMPZoomTransitionAnimating
   func transitionSourceImageView() -> UIImageView {
        return imageView
    }

    func transitionSourceBackgroundColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    func transitionDestinationImageViewFrame() -> CGRect {
        return imageView.frame
    }
```

This will tell the compiler your class is objective-c compatible