# Why does Swift's enumerateSubstringsInRange callback take an optional string?

Tags: swift, option-type

We can extract words from a Swift string like this:

```
s.enumerateSubstringsInRange(s.characters.indices, options: .ByWords) {
    (w,_,_,_) in print(w!)
}
```

but the forced unwrapping is generally a code smell. It is there because the first parameter of the callback is a `String?` (an optional). I've tried several possible strings in order to force the function to pass `nil` to the callback (e.g. the empty string, and strings with no word characters) but with no luck!

So I was wondering *why* the callback takes an optional string. Is there something I overlooked? Is it because a mutable string can be passed in and modified concurrently? If so, then would it be acceptable practice, if I know my original string is a constant (defined with `let`), to do the forced unwrap?

Comment: Doing a forced unwrap is effectively never okay.  Even if you *want* your program to crash when you get `nil`, it's far better to do something like `guard let` unwrap it and throw a fatal error with a useful description of what went wrong.

Comment: That aside, do you get `nil` in the case that you're using `.ByWords` and have a double-space somewhere in your string, by any chance?

Comment: I do avoid `!` at all times, but in this case the idea that _immutable strings might never produce `nil`_ just got me wondering. I could be wrong about this, though, hence the question. And to the second comment: double spaces do not generate `nil`s. Neither does a string full of non-word characters. I am at a loss on how to generate a `nil` for the callback.

Comment: I'm not sure either.  Seems like the only solution would be to ask Apple (in terms of why it's `String?` versus `String`).

Comment: They would know indeed, but I would be happy to just look at the source code myself but I can't find it. I googled NSString source code and Foundation source code. but `enumerateSubstringsInRange` were not in any of the files I found.

Comment: Even if you did find it, it'd not be written in Swift.  It'd be in Objective-C & C.  And the only thing that'd make it optional versus non-optional is the existence of a [nullability annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29401454/2792531): `__nullable`.

Comment: @nhgrif I think he can not use guard there because it is not a loop or a method. He needs to safely unwrap it using if let substring = substring { ... }

Comment: @LeoDabus: You *can* use guard in a closure, the `else { return }` case would then return from the closure immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(The following information is from the response to my question
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/28272 in the 
Apple Developer Forum.)*

You can pass the `.SubstringNotRequired` option to `enumerateSubstringsInRange()`, and then the closure will be called with
`substring == nil`. This option is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/struct/c:@E@NSStringEnumerationOptions) as

> **NSStringEnumerationSubstringNotRequired**
>
> A way to indicate that the block does not need substring, in which
>   case nil will be passed. This is simply a performance shortcut.

Example:

```
let str = "Hello, playground"  
str.enumerateSubstringsInRange(str.characters.indices,
    options: [.ByWords, .SubstringNotRequired]) {
        substring, substringRange, _, _ in  
        print(substring, substringRange)  
}
```

Output:

```
nil 0..<5
nil 7..<17
```

I think it is safe to assume that `substring != nil` if the
`.SubstringNotRequired` option is not given.

Comment: This is fascinating and definitely answers the question, but my mind is completely unable to fathom why that ever would be a good idea. If one is enumerating strings, even via some bizarre filter, I would think that you just pass the strings you find to the closure, and don't pass strings you don't find. Why `nil` is ever a useful thing to enumerate I still can't wrap my head around.

Comment: @RayToal: With the `.SubstringNotRequired` option, the closure is still called for every word, and `subStringRange` is set to its range. As "OOPer" says in the referenced forum thread, that *might* increase performance if you only need the ranges but not the actual strings.